# How to change "user" name? (Only account)

Tags: gnome-terminal, root, users, username

I'm trying to change the name that is listed as "user" under my desired username. This is the only account I have set up (= root account?).

I noticed that the name "user" instead of the account username appears in the terminal ("user"@). Note that my computer name has been set up as "ub".

How do I change the text under my username from "user" to match that of my username?

Screenshot:

[image]

I'm a newbie with ubuntu so if someone can list out clear step-by-step instructions I would be most grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: Whats the output of `echo "$PS1"`?

Comment: What do you get when you run `whoami ; echo $HOME` at the command prompt?

Comment: @heemayl  Output of `echo "$PS1"` in Terminal is `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]u@\h\[\033[00m\]:[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ `
@L.D.James Output of `whoami ; echo $HOME` in Terminal is `user /home/user` with a line brake after the first `user` before `/home ...`

Comment: Type in the name exactly the way you want it to appear.  At present it's showing your actually username with is `user`.  You can change your username to something different, or you can edit your `$PS1` variable to output any other specification outside of your actual username.  As per your question, I'll outline in a formatted answer how to do it both ways.

Answer (score 1):

`enter code here`The out put is showing you your username which is `user`.

You can either change your `username` or change the `PS1` variable.  Only do #1 or #2.

**#1 Change your username to a name of your choice**

The best way is to login via different account.  The specific user account can't be active when making this modification.  So you may have to create a temporary account with `sudo` active, if you don't already have one.

Then from the other account run this command:

```
$ sudo usermod -l newname user
```

The parameter `user` is the current name being changed.  The `newname` is what it's being changed to.

Then you will have to move the directory to that new name.  Do this with:

```
$ sudo usermod -d /home/user -m newname
```

**#2 Change the PS1 variable in your `~/.bashrc` file**

If you just want to have your name displayed in a special way you can edit the `PS1`variable in your `~/.bashrc` file.  You can use the line below or any other variation.  In this case the `newname` in the line is what you would change to what you want to appear in your terminal prompt.

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]newname@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

**Adding user from the commandline**

You can add a user from the commandline with:

```
$ sudo adduser usernametoadd
```

You can add this user to `sudoer` access with:

```
$ sudo adduser usernametoadd sudo
```

Comment: How do I ensure my temporary account has `sudo` active? Will creating a temporary administrator account work?

Comment: When you the account if you're using the `GUI` (by way of the Gear icon in the top right -> System Settings -> User Accounts), Choose `Administrator` as the `Account Type`.  You could also add it to the sudoer's access from the commandline with: `sudo adduser usertoadd sudo`.

Comment: @user604803 I added formatted steps for creating a user and ensuring he has `sudo` access to the answer.